# list index out of range ao tentar resolver questão do google developer day 2010

Tags: python, python-3.x, google

Primeiramente, vou copiar aqui o enunciado da questão para se situarem:

Na pacata vila campestre de Ponteironuloville, todos os telefones têm 6 dígitos. A companhia telefônica estabelece as seguintes regras sobre os números:

1. Não pode haver dois dígitos consecutivos idênticos, porque isso é chato;
2. A soma dos dígitos tem que ser par, porque isso é legal;
3. O último dígito não pode ser igual ao primeiro, porque isso dá azar.

Então, dadas essas regras perfeitamente razoáveis, bem projetadas e maduras, quantos números de telefone na lista abaixo são válidos?
(A lista da questão está no começo do meu código.)

Dado o enunciado, eis a minha tentativa de resolução:

```
lista = '''213752 216732 221063 221545 225583 229133 230648 233222 236043 237330
         239636 240138 242123 246224 249183 252936 254711 257200 257607 261424
         263814 266794 268649 273050 275001 277606 278997 283331 287104 287953
         289137 291591 292559 292946 295180 295566 297529 300400 304707 306931
         310638 313595 318449 319021 322082 323796 326266 326880 327249 329914
         334392 334575 336723 336734 338808 343269 346040 350113 353631 357154
         361633 361891 364889 365746 365749 366426 369156 369444 369689 372896
         374983 375223 379163 380712 385640 386777 388599 389450 390178 392943
         394742 395921 398644 398832 401149 402219 405364 408088 412901 417683
         422267 424767 426613 430474 433910 435054 440052 444630 447852 449116
         453865 457631 461750 462985 463328 466458 469601 473108 476773 477956
         481991 482422 486195 488359 489209 489388 491928 496569 496964 497901
         500877 502386 502715 507617 512526 512827 513796 518232 521455 524277
         528496 529345 531231 531766 535067 535183 536593 537360 539055 540582
         543708 547492 550779 551595 556493 558807 559102 562050 564962 569677
         570945 575447 579937 580112 580680 582458 583012 585395 586244 587393
         590483 593112 593894 594293 597525 598184 600455 600953 601523 605761
         608618 609198 610141 610536 612636 615233 618314 622752 626345 626632
         628889 629457 629643 633673 637656 641136 644176 644973 647617 652218
         657143 659902 662224 666265 668010 672480 672695 676868 677125 678315'''

lista = lista.split()
#como simplesmente copiei a lista, não quis separar 200 elementos manualmente.

validos = []
#lista vazia onde irei inserir os números válidos.

for ca in range(len(lista)):
    n_inv = False
    e = list(lista[ca])
    for cb in range(len(e) - 1):
        cc = cb + 1
        if e[cb] == e[cc]:
            n_inv = True
    if n_inv == False:
        validos.append(lista[ca])
#2 loops(externo e interno) para selecionar os números de acordo com a primeira 
#condição dada, até aqui tudo bem.


for ca in range(len(validos)):
    a = 0
    e = list(validos[ca]) #o IDLE acusa o erro aqui(list index out of range)
    for cb in range(len(e)):
        a += int(e[cb])
    if a % 2 != 0:
        del validos[ca]
#loop para filtrar os números anteriormente selecionados de acordo com a condição 2.

for ca in range(len(validos)):
    e = list(validos[ca])
    if e[0] == e[-1]:
        del validos[ca]
#loop para filtrar os números anteriormente selecionados de acordo com a condição 3.

print(len(validos))
```

Já estou há algumas horas quebrando a cabeça pra fazer esse código. Já tive alguns outros problemas com ele, mas consegui resolver, principalmente com a ajuda do python tutor. Esse eu não consigo visualizar a execução porque o site limita os loops em 300 pra evitar loopings infinitos. Se puderem me ajudar mais essa vez, agradeço muito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olha, não entendo de python, mas acho que neste trecho:

```
for ca in range(len(validos)):
    a = 0
    e = list(validos[ca]) #o IDLE acusa o erro aqui(list index out of range)
    for cb in range(len(e)):
        a += int(e[cb])
    if a % 2 != 0:
        del validos[ca]
```

Você está deletando os elementos da lista ao mesmo tempo que está iterando ela. Como resultado, durante a iteração, a lista diminui de tamanho, mas você ainda tenta acessar todos os elementos como se ainda estivessem ali. O resultado é que uma hora você vai acabar tentando acessar um elemento fora da lista.

Penso nas seguintes soluções:

- Reprojetar o laço para incrementar o `ca` apenas se o elemento não tiver sido removido.
- Ao invés de remover os elementos da lista, substituí-los por alguma coisa que indica que devam ser desconsiderados (por exemplo, um zero) e então no final você conta quantos elementos não são zeros.
- Ao invés de remover os elementos inválidos da lista, copiar os válidos para uma outra lista que será então usada na etapa seguinte.
- Iterar a lista de números apenas uma vez, já verificando as três condições em uma mesma iteração. E então, basta manter um contador de quantos números válidos você encontrou. Com isso, você não precisa alterar e nem excluir elementos e nem inserí-los em listas auxiliares.

Comment: Estranho, eu pensei que sempre que eu removesse um elemento, quando eu voltasse pro começo do loop ele ia atualizar o tamanho da lista `validos` então eu não teria esse problema(já que a condição de parada pro loop é o próprio tamanho da lista). Tentei modificar com while, conforme você disse, mas o erro persistiu:

ca = 0
while ca <= len(validos):
    a = 0
    e = list(validos[ca])
    for cb in range(len(e)):
        a += int(e[cb])
    if a % 2 != 0:
        del validos[ca]
    else:
        ca += 1

Porém, deu certo ao transformar os números inválidos em `'0'` e removê-los depois.

Comment: @JeffersonCarvalho Acredito que por questão de desempenho, ele só vai avaliar o `range(len(validos))` uma vez. Pelo menos em todas as outras linguagens que conheço, é isso que acontece. Quanto a modificar o `while`, você usou `ca <= len(validos)`, mas deveria ser `ca < len(validos)`.

Answer (score 2):

Como [mencionado pelo Victor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54326/6454), o problema acontece quando você utiliza o [`del`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement) para remover o item da lista. Isso acontece nos dois últimos laços `for` do código:

```
for ca in range(len(validos))
    ...
    del validos[ca]
```

A expressão `len(validos)` é avaliada somente **uma** vez, no momento em que `range` é avaliado. Quando você remove um elemento seja por `pop` ou `del`, a exceção [`IndexError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IndexError) é gerada.

Como bem citado pelo Victor, ao invés de remover os números inválidos, copie somente os válidos para a lista `validos`.

Poderia também ser economizado algumas linhas de código avaliando as condições no mesmo laço `for`.

O seu código com essas modificações pode ficar assim:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

lista = '''213752 216732 221063 221545 225583 229133 230648 233222 236043 237330
         239636 240138 242123 246224 249183 252936 254711 257200 257607 261424
         263814 266794 268649 273050 275001 277606 278997 283331 287104 287953
         289137 291591 292559 292946 295180 295566 297529 300400 304707 306931
         310638 313595 318449 319021 322082 323796 326266 326880 327249 329914
         334392 334575 336723 336734 338808 343269 346040 350113 353631 357154
         361633 361891 364889 365746 365749 366426 369156 369444 369689 372896
         374983 375223 379163 380712 385640 386777 388599 389450 390178 392943
         394742 395921 398644 398832 401149 402219 405364 408088 412901 417683
         422267 424767 426613 430474 433910 435054 440052 444630 447852 449116
         453865 457631 461750 462985 463328 466458 469601 473108 476773 477956
         481991 482422 486195 488359 489209 489388 491928 496569 496964 497901
         500877 502386 502715 507617 512526 512827 513796 518232 521455 524277
         528496 529345 531231 531766 535067 535183 536593 537360 539055 540582
         543708 547492 550779 551595 556493 558807 559102 562050 564962 569677
         570945 575447 579937 580112 580680 582458 583012 585395 586244 587393
         590483 593112 593894 594293 597525 598184 600455 600953 601523 605761
         608618 609198 610141 610536 612636 615233 618314 622752 626345 626632
         628889 629457 629643 633673 637656 641136 644176 644973 647617 652218
         657143 659902 662224 666265 668010 672480 672695 676868 677125 678315'''

lista = lista.split()
validos = []

for indice in range(len(lista)):
    soma = 0
    ff = 0
    invalido = True
    elemento = list(lista[indice])
    soma = sum(map(int, elemento))
    for caractere in range(len(elemento) -1):
        proximoCaractere = caractere + 1    
        if (elemento[caractere] == elemento[proximoCaractere]) or (int(soma) % 2 != 0) or (elemento[0] == elemento[-1]):
            invalido = True
            break
        else:
            invalido = False

    if invalido == False:       
        validos.append(elemento)    

print ("Válidos: {0} / Original: {1}".format(len(validos), len(lista)))
```

Exemplo funcional no [**repl.it**](http://repl.it/dz0).

Comment: Interessante, realmente o código ficou bem menor. Mas a resposta acabou saindo errado, o seu código gerou 76 e o correto seria 39. Talvez isso tenha acontecido porque você se esqueceu de somar os números dos elementos antes de verificar se ele era par.

Comment: @JeffersonCarvalho Desculpe-me já corrigi o código. =)

Answer (score 1):

Achei interessante a questão e gostaria complementar com uma solução com uma cara mais OO.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from itertools import tee


class ListaTelefones(object):

    def __init__(self, lista_de_telefones):
        self.telefones = lista_de_telefones.split()
        self.telefones_validos = []
        self.telefones_invalidos = []

    def dois_a_dois(self, iterable):
        "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
        a, b = tee(iterable)
        next(b, None)
        return zip(a, b)

    def digitos_consecutivos_identicos(self, telefone):
        """ Não pode haver dois dígitos consecutivos idênticos,
            porque isso é chato. """
        return all([True if el1 != el2 else False
                   for el1, el2 in self.dois_a_dois(telefone)])

    def soma_digitos_e_par(self, telefone):
        """ A soma dos dígitos tem que ser par, porque isso é legal. """
        return sum(map(int, telefone)) % 2 == 0

    def primeiro_e_ultimo_digito_diferentes(self, telefone):
        """ O último dígito não pode ser igual ao primeiro,
            porque isso dá azar. """
        return telefone[0] != telefone[-1]

    def checar_validade(self, telefone):
        condicao1 = self.digitos_consecutivos_identicos(telefone)
        condicao2 = self.soma_digitos_e_par(telefone)
        condicao3 = self.primeiro_e_ultimo_digito_diferentes(telefone)
        return all([condicao1, condicao2, condicao3, ])

    def obter_telefones_validos(self):
        self.telefones_validos = []
        for li in self.telefones:
            if self.checar_validade(li):
                self.telefones_validos.append(li)

    def imprimir_telefones(self):
        for li in self.telefones:
            print(li)

    def imprimir_telefones_validos(self):
        for li in self.telefones_validos:
            print(li)

    def contar_telefones(self):
        print(len(self.telefones))

    def contar_telefones_validos(self):
        print(len(self.telefones_validos))


lista = '''213752 216732 221063 221545 225583 229133 230648 233222 236043 237330
         239636 240138 242123 246224 249183 252936 254711 257200 257607 261424
         263814 266794 268649 273050 275001 277606 278997 283331 287104 287953
         289137 291591 292559 292946 295180 295566 297529 300400 304707 306931
         310638 313595 318449 319021 322082 323796 326266 326880 327249 329914
         334392 334575 336723 336734 338808 343269 346040 350113 353631 357154
         361633 361891 364889 365746 365749 366426 369156 369444 369689 372896
         374983 375223 379163 380712 385640 386777 388599 389450 390178 392943
         394742 395921 398644 398832 401149 402219 405364 408088 412901 417683
         422267 424767 426613 430474 433910 435054 440052 444630 447852 449116
         453865 457631 461750 462985 463328 466458 469601 473108 476773 477956
         481991 482422 486195 488359 489209 489388 491928 496569 496964 497901
         500877 502386 502715 507617 512526 512827 513796 518232 521455 524277
         528496 529345 531231 531766 535067 535183 536593 537360 539055 540582
         543708 547492 550779 551595 556493 558807 559102 562050 564962 569677
         570945 575447 579937 580112 580680 582458 583012 585395 586244 587393
         590483 593112 593894 594293 597525 598184 600455 600953 601523 605761
         608618 609198 610141 610536 612636 615233 618314 622752 626345 626632
         628889 629457 629643 633673 637656 641136 644176 644973 647617 652218
         657143 659902 662224 666265 668010 672480 672695 676868 677125 678315'''


lista_telefones = ListaTelefones(lista_de_telefones=lista)
lista_telefones.obter_telefones_validos()
lista_telefones.imprimir_telefones_validos()
lista_telefones.contar_telefones_validos()
```

https://gist.github.com/arthuralvim/f0e7f62414e4ade71745

Comment: Boa parte desse código eu ainda não entendo pois sou iniciante, rs
Mas pelo menos a resposta final está correta, que é 39.